# PHP Curl Post - JSON Decoding Error

Tags: php, json, post, curl, decode

I need to use PHP curl to post JSON data. After searching this site, I found some examples and learned that data should be submitted as array, but I still get "({"message":"cjson decoding error","code":500,"error":true})" error every time after posting data.

The original data looks like this (from firefox live httpd headers):

```
{"nodes":[{"id":"","type":"some_type","parentId":"ROOT","refId":null,"href":"","text":"New","desc":"","tags":"","cr":123}],"revision":11,"token":"some_token"}
```

Now, here's the data I try to submit via curl

```
json_encode(array("nodes"=>array("id"=>"", "type"=>"some_type", "parentId"=>"ROOT", "refId"=>"", "href"=>"", "text"=>"New", "desc"=>"", "tags"=>"", "cr"=>"123"), "revision"=>"11", "token"=>"some_token"));
```

Could someone tell me what's wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

If you echo the second line, you'll see that it doesn't match what you posted in the first line.

The correct version would be the following:

```
json_encode(array("nodes"=>array(array("id"=>"", "type"=>"some_type", "parentId"=>"ROOT", "refId"=>"", "href"=>"", "text"=>"New", "desc"=>"", "tags"=>"", "cr"=>"123")), "revision"=>"11", "token"=>"some_token"));
```

Now it's the same structure as what you posted in the first line. (See the additional array around the list of nodes. You need that additional array() there because the format seems to support the idea of posting more than one "node".

Comment: Unfortunately, the same error is still displayed. Will need to play around a bit more...

Comment: If you compare the two different HTTP requests (the one you want to emulate and the one you set off manually) - are there any differences?

Comment: How could I compare them? I simply use livehttpdheaders plugin to see what dyte is being posted, and then use curl to post the same stuff (including referrers, etc)

Comment: If you echo the json_encode part I posted above, you get the JSON formatted version of the array, which should look exactly like what you posted initially. You can then compare that character by character to get *exactly* the same JSON. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I did as suggested and found that ORIGINAL request has extra [ and ] tags (except those, everything is the same):

Original data
`{"nodes":[{"id":"","type":"some_type","parentId":"ROOT","refId":null,"href":"","text":"New","desc":"","tags":"","cr":123}],"revision":11,"token":"some_token"}`

My data:
`{"nodes":{"id":"","type":"some_type","parentId":"ROOT","refId":null,"href":"","text":"New","desc":"","tags":"","cr":123},"revision":"11","token":"some_token"}`

Comment: Unfortunately, no (probably because original data has extra [ and ] tags. Not very sure where and how I should add them to my data

Comment: [ and ] stands for an array, whereas { and } stands for an object. so put array(...) around the object that should be enclosed by the [ and ] tags.
Look into the line of code I wrote in the question above. (Note that an associative array will be encoded as an object ({..}) whereas an indexed array will be parsed as an array ([...]).)